# lightning $A.enqueueAction(action) does not work!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, jquery

I have external jqGrid component setup with lightning. On initialization, it calls controller's function 'jsLoaded'. This function initially loads the data into grid. Everything works great up to here. Now, i have edit events on the grid which have function binding. But when save event is raised, function is called correctly, constructs action object and sObject parameter but when submit to $A.enqueueAction, nothing happens, no errors!

See the attached screenshot for the code: [[image]][[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXe3v.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `helper.sendPerson()` is called by jQuery which happens outside of Lightning's execution context. You need to wrap the jQuery's bind function within `$A.getCallback()` to make it execute within the Lightning's context.

```
j$('#jqGrid').bind('something',$A.getCallback(function(params){
  //logic
}));
```

Please refer this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/158494/20830) it solves similar problem.